# Django admin, page not found in custom view

Tags: python, django

I encountered very annoying problem.

I have created my own `AdminSite` like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.urls import path

class MyAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            path('statistics/', self.admin_view(self.statistics), name='statistics'),
        ]
        return urls + my_urls

    def statistics(self, request):
        context = dict(
            self.each_context(request),
        )
        return TemplateResponse(request, 'admin/statistics.html', context)
```

I have created my own `AdminConfig` and assigned it into my `INSTALLED_APPS`, created html file, then in my root urls added it like this:

```
 urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
 ]
```

I have logged in into my admin page and when I'm trying to open  `localhost:8000/admin/statistics` I receive this:

```
Page not found (404)
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/statistics/
```

Why this is happening? Did I miss something?

**Update**

I have added print on my get_urls and it showed this.(I removed unnecessary urls):

```
[
<URLPattern '' [name='index']>, 
<URLPattern 'login/' [name='login']>, 
<URLPattern 'logout/' [name='logout']>, 
<URLPattern 'password_change/' [name='password_change']>, 
<URLPattern 'password_change/done/' [name='password_change_done']>, 
<URLPattern 'autocomplete/' [name='autocomplete']>, 
<URLPattern 'jsi18n/' [name='jsi18n']>, 
<URLPattern 'r/<int:content_type_id>/<path:object_id>/' [name='view_on_site']>, 
<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (None:None) 'auth/group/'>,  
<URLPattern '(?P<url>.*)$'>, 
<URLPattern 'statistics/' [name='statistics']>
]
```

Using `python manage.py show_urls | grep statistics` shows me this:

```
/admin/statistics/   project.admin.statistics    admin:statistics
```

Comment: Check out [this link in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class). I think you need to add the custom admin urls as well to the `ROOT_URL_CONF` directly or indirectly.

Comment: @Mugoma I don't understand. I've already included my own configs and when I add `print` in my `get_urls` it shows this new url

Comment: Can you show the output of get_urls?

Comment: Hmm can you also add the output of `python manage.py show_urls | grep statistics`

Comment: @bdbd Added show_urls result

Comment: simple debug question: have you tried to invert order of return in your `get_url` function? like `return my_urls + urls`

Comment: @lucascavalcante IT WORKED!!! WHISKEY TANGO FOXTROT!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well. I'm going to answer to my own question, in order to help other people.

The solution of this problem was to switch returning url addition like this:

```
 return my_urls + urls
```

`my_urls` comes first and the other `urls`.

Why this is happening? Because `urls'` last path contains some kind of big wildcard url that just overwrites my own. That is why I needed to add first my new urls.

Thanks for @lucascavalcante

Comment: To be precise, it doesn't overwrite your own, rather it matches all urls and is placed before your urls. A bit confusing, and not easy to spot is, that you can list your urls with `manage.py show_urls`, and it will show all your urls. But it includes `catch_all_view` before your urls.

Answer (score 2):

Try invert the order of return in your `get_url` function:

```
return my_urls + urls
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this might work

```
return my_urls + urls
```